# Find The Automorphism Group

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I am taking my first course in Geometry and Topology and we are seeing the automorphism group of a covering. In class, my teacher gave some graphs and their automorphism groups, but he did not explain how he got the automorphims groups from them. He said that these automorphism group correspond to permutation of the fibers of the eight figure, could somebody explain how he got this? I think the first one is a 4-degree cover, the second one a 3-degree cover.
[image]

Comment: Which part is confusing you? That the automorphism groups are $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$ etc, or the connection between subgroups and particular covers, or something else?

Comment: I do not understand how did he get that the automorphism groups are $\mathbb{Z}_{2}...$

Comment: @LeonhardLeibniz: just look at the preimage $X$ of the base point. An automorphism induces a permutation of $X$, and in these cases automorphisms are determined by how they act on $X$. It only remains to check which permutations of $X$ are induced by an automorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider the first picture. There are four vertices, and they can be permuted by reflecting in a horizontal line or a vertical line. These two reflections generate the group $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$. The double-arrowed lines need to map to themselves as do the single-arrowed lines, so there are no more automorphisms. For example rotation by 90 degrees is ruled out. The second one is not drawn correctly. In the lower-left there should be a single arrowed line. Then rotations by 120 degrees give the automorphism group. For the last picture, an obvious automorphism is translation by an even number of units. This corresponds to the index $4$ subgroup generated by the word $ab$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$. There's also reflections through the double arrow edges or the single arrow edges, which together with $ab$ generate the entire automorphism group.

Comment: Thank you Grumpy and Thomasz, it was easier than I thought.